# Javascript to add four & subtract two images every second

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a website where every second, four images would appear on a random location on the page, and then two images would disappear afterwards. So four images would appear in half a second, and two would disappear in half a second, making it a one second execution.

I am trying to make a visual representation that four people are born and two people pass away every second on earth. I am using a single image called "sunflower.png" to execute this.

My friend suggested I start out my code like this, but I cannot get it to work properly. Instead, my picture would pop up for a second, and then an image error icon would keep repeating afterwards. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
    .sunflower {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="maincontainer">
    
    <img class="sunflower" src="images/sunflower.png" alt="Sunflower">
        
    </div>
    
<script>
    function deleteImage() {
    const imagesAlreadyOnScreen = document.getElementsByClassName("sunflower"); 
    const indexToRemove = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesAlreadyOnScreen.length);
    imagesAlreadyOnScreen[indexToRemove].remove();
    }

    const parentElement = document.getElementById("maincontainer");

    function addImage() {
        const img = document.createElement("img");


        img.setAttribute('src', 'imageLink'); 
        
        parentElement.appendChild(img) 
    }

window.setInterval(deleteImage, 500); 
    
window.setInterval(addImage, 250);
    
    
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/bGNGbgx?editors=1111)

First of all, we need some kind of grid so that we don't display a picture of a person on top of another person's picture. I have created a sample 10x10 grid that contains images of 100px x 100px.

I have created a Class for the Person objects that will be created and removed according to the birth and death intervals.

According to the number of available grid positions, I initialize an Array of 100 elements (maximum number of people), ranging from 0 to 99.

The birth Interval is set, and every 500ms, 4 new People (objects) are born.

Then, after 1000ms, the death Interval kicks in, and 2 people die.

Of course, it's just a sample code to get you started. You can completely remove the Grid logic and use just random x, y positions on the parent element.

You can also comment out the transform CSS rule to see the grid in full size.

```js
// All the positions that the grid can hold: 0-99
const grid = [...Array(100)].map(( _, idx ) => idx);

// Get a random position (0-99) from the grid Array:
function getRandomPos(){
  return grid.splice( Math.floor( Math.random() * grid.length -1 ), 1 )[0];
}

// Get the x and y grid coordinates from the random position:
function getXYfromPos( randomPos ){
  const x = randomPos % 10;
  const y = Math.floor( randomPos / 10 );
  return { x, y }
}

// Get a random person (that will die) from the people array, which holds all currently living persons:
function getRandomPerson(){
  return people[ Math.floor( Math.random() * people.length - 1 ) ];  
}

// A URL to display random images:
const URL = [ "https://picsum.photos/id", "100/100" ];

// A counter to be incremented, so that every time a new person is created, we get a new image:
let counter = 0;

// The array that will be holding the people that are born:
const people = [];

class Person {
  
  constructor(){
    this.img = document.createElement("img");
    this.img.setAttribute( "src", `${URL[0]}/${++counter}/${URL[1]}` );
    this.randomPos = getRandomPos(); 
    const xy = getXYfromPos( this.randomPos )
    this.x = xy.x;
    this.y = xy.y;
    this.img.style.left = ( this.x * 100 )+ 'px';
    this.img.style.top = ( this.y * 100 ) + 'px';
    document.querySelector("#content").appendChild( this.img );
    people.push( this );
  }
  
  remove(){
    this.img.remove();
    grid.push(this.randomPos);
    people.splice( people.indexOf( this ), 1 );
  }

}

let birthInterval;
let deathInterval;

function start(){

birthInterval = setInterval(function(){

    new Person();
    new Person();
    new Person();
    new Person();
    // console.log( "4 people are born :)" ); 
    if ( !deathInterval ){

        deathInterval = setInterval(function(){

        const randomPerson1 = getRandomPerson();
        randomPerson1 && randomPerson1.remove();
        const randomPerson2 = getRandomPerson();
        randomPerson2 && randomPerson2.remove();
        // console.log( "2 people die :(" ); 

        }, 500  );

    }

}, 500 );

}


document.querySelector("#start").onclick = start;
document.querySelector("#stop").onclick = function(){
  clearInterval( birthInterval );
  clearInterval( deathInterval );
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}
#content{
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient( 0deg, white 0%, white 1%, transparent 2%, transparent),
    linear-gradient( 90deg, white 0%, white 1%, transparent 2%, transparent);
  background-size:100px 100px;
  transform: scale(0.6) translateY(-200px);
}
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button><button id="stop">Stop</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things with the images you're adding:

a) The src attribute needs to be set to 'images/sunflower.png' - this will stop your broken image issue

b) It needs a class of 'sunflower' so that it shows up in your list of deletable images

```
function addImage() {
    const img = document.createElement("img");    

    img.setAttribute('src', 'images/sunflower.png');

    img.classList.add('sunflower');

    parentElement.appendChild(img) 
}
```